# Wordpress hook in a plugin cannot be found from file in theme

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I have created a custom hook in a plugin that creates a PDF using a library. I also have a class file that extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base that runs when a form is submitted. This part also works.

The problem now is that the hook cannot be found from within this class file. However it can be found from within functions.php

So the class file looks something like this:

```php
class RunOnFormSubmit extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base
{
//...
public function run() {
/* I now for sure this function is called and runs */
do_action("prefixed_action", $arg1, $arg2) // This action cannot be found
}
//...
}
```

The plugin then looks something like this:

```php
add_action("prefixed_action", "createPDF", 10, 2)

function createPDF($arg1, $arg2) {
// This function works
}
```

I tested using the has_action function and the functions.php file can find the hook, but it cannot be found in the run method of the class.

Does this have something to do with the order at which the files are loaded in?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there might be an issue if your plugin is loaded before Elementor Pro itself. The solution to wrap code declaration into a function and init it with elementor_pro/init:

```
add_action('elementor_pro/init', 'custom_register_action');

function custom_register_action() {
    class Custom_Action extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base {

        public function get_name() {
            return 'cust_action';
        }

        public function get_label() {
            return __( 'Custom Action');
        }

        public function register_settings_section( $widget ) {
        // Add your settings here
    }

        public function on_export( $element ) {
            // Implement this method if you need to handle the action when exporting an Elementor template
        }

        public function run( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
            // Implement your custom code
        }
    }

    $custom_action = new Custom_Action();
    \ElementorPro\Plugin::instance()->modules_manager->get_modules( 'forms' )->add_form_action( $custom_action->get_name(), $custom_action );
}
```